# Why is my static text appearing in the default position (wxPython Phoenix)?

Tags: python, position, wxpython, static-text

I recently started learning python and even more recently decided to try my hand at learning how to give my code a GUI (using wxPython Phoenix). Just when I thought I was starting to get the basics however, I tried to add static text to a panel through an event. Though the correct message is displayed it appears at the top left corner of the panel despite my location specification. If I resize the frame it goes to it's correct position, but obviously I'd like it to go there directly.

I've tried only running the program once I've made the frame larger (assuming space was the issue) and using a scroll panel but neither have worked. I've been looking through the documentation but cannot quite figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is a reduced version of the code (I left out the elif/else statements because they are essentially the same with varying strings):

```
import wx
import random

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        txt1 = wx.StaticText(self, label="How many sides to your dice?")
        self.sizer.Add(txt1, 0, wx.TOP | wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.spin = wx.SpinCtrl(self, min=-200, max=200)
        self.sizer.Add(self.spin, 0, wx.BOTTOM | wx.CENTER, 5)

        txt2 = wx.StaticText(self, label="How many dice are you rolling?")
        self.sizer.Add(txt2, 0, wx.TOP | wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.spin2 = wx.SpinCtrl(self, min=-200, max=200)
        self.sizer.Add(self.spin2, 0, wx.BOTTOM | wx.CENTER, 5)

        txt3 = wx.StaticText(self, label="If you have any modifiers add them here!")
        self.sizer.Add(txt3, 0, wx.TOP | wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.spin3 = wx.SpinCtrl(self, min=-200, max=200)
        self.sizer.Add(self.spin3, 0, wx.BOTTOM | wx.CENTER, 5)

        bttn = wx.Button(self, label="Roll 'em")
        self.sizer.Add(bttn, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 10)
        bttn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_push)

        self.size = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        box = wx.StaticBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, """Your Roll Results will display here!
        """)
        self.size.Add(box, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.sizer.Add(self.size, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5)

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

    def on_push(self, event):
        d_size = self.spin.GetValue()
        d_amount = self.spin2.GetValue()
        mod = self.spin3.GetValue()

        mx_am = d_size * d_amount
        mn_am = d_amount
        bot_quart = mx_am * 0.25
        half = mx_am / 2
        three_quart = mx_am - bot_quart

        if int(d_size) < 0 or int(d_amount) < 0:
            message = "Sorry, you entered a negative where that is impossible."
            errtxt = wx.StaticText(self, label=message)
            self.size.Add(errtxt, 0, wx.BOTTOM | wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None, title='Dice Roller')

        self.panel = MyPanel(self)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Like I said, errtext appears first at the top left corner of the frame and then, upon resizing the frame, drops to the correct position. Any possible help is much appreciated (especially if you can tell me how to get errtext into the static box).

Answer (score 0):

It probably just needs a `self.Layout()` instruction, due to the nested `sizers`.
A `StaticBox` is probably not the best choice for your results either.
StaticBoxes come with their own `sizer` a `StaticBoxSizer` and are for presenting static information.
`SpinCtrl`'s, as you have observed come with a mimimum value, so I'd suggest that be set to something like 6 rather than -200.
I've taken the liberty of making some minor adjustments to your code, including making the error text an integral part of the screen, rather than adding it in ad-hoc.
Were you planning on removing it, ad-hoc, as well?

```
import wx
import random

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        txt1 = wx.StaticText(self, label="How many sides to your dice?")
        self.sizer.Add(txt1, 0, wx.TOP | wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.spin = wx.SpinCtrl(self, min=-200, max=200)
        self.sizer.Add(self.spin, 0, wx.BOTTOM | wx.CENTER, 5)

        txt2 = wx.StaticText(self, label="How many dice are you rolling?")
        self.sizer.Add(txt2, 0, wx.TOP | wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.spin2 = wx.SpinCtrl(self, min=-200, max=200)
        self.sizer.Add(self.spin2, 0, wx.BOTTOM | wx.CENTER, 5)

        txt3 = wx.StaticText(self, label="If you have any modifiers add them here!")
        self.sizer.Add(txt3, 0, wx.TOP | wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.spin3 = wx.SpinCtrl(self, min=-200, max=200)
        self.sizer.Add(self.spin3, 0, wx.BOTTOM | wx.CENTER, 5)

        bttn = wx.Button(self, label="Roll 'em")
        self.sizer.Add(bttn, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 10)
        bttn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_push)

        self.size = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.box = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Results", style=wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.errtxt = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label="")
        self.size.Add(self.box, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.size.Add(self.errtxt, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.sizer.Add(self.size, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

    def on_push(self, event):
        d_size = self.spin.GetValue()
        d_amount = self.spin2.GetValue()
        mod = self.spin3.GetValue()

        mx_am = d_size * d_amount
        mn_am = d_amount
        bot_quart = mx_am * 0.25
        half = mx_am / 2
        three_quart = mx_am - bot_quart

        if int(d_size) < 0 or int(d_amount) < 0:
            message = "Sorry, you entered a negative where that is impossible."
            self.errtxt.SetLabel(message)
        else:
            self.errtxt.SetLabel("")
        self.box.SetValue(str(three_quart))
        self.Layout()

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None, title='Dice Roller')

        self.panel = MyPanel(self)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]